# error in installing RWeka package in R

Tags: r

After getting RWeka package is sucessfully unpacked, when command `library("RWeka")` is executed it is showing an error:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>   call: fun(libname, pkgname)   error: No CurrentVersion entry in
>   Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and
>   Java have matching architectures. In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘RWeka’ was built under R version 3.2.3  Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’

Comment: Surya, the error message is clear. "Try reinstalling Java" .....

Comment: When asking a question on Stackoverflow it is useful to actually provide some context, explain what steps you have tried in your troubleshooting, format your entry nicely, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, make sure you have Java installed of the same architecture as R. For example if you have `32-bit` R, you need to have `32-bit` Java installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is 32 bit, get yourself a 32-Bit java. If the system is 64-Bit go for 64bit java. I faced the same issue as my system is 64-Bit and i accidentally installed 32-Bit java. Uninstalled and reinstalled a 64-bit. Sorted now.